# joining column values by comma for in operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following xml format

```
<Request  SearchType="CUSIPISIN">
                  <Identifiers>
                       <Identifier id="US04012VAA70"/>
                       <Identifier id="553061AA0"/>
                  </Identifiers>
       </Request>
```

in my sql server stored proc

```
alter  PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search]
    @RequestXml XML

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @SearchType varchar(50);
    set @SearchType= @requestXml.value('(//Request/@SearchType)[1]', 'varchar(10)')


    SELECT Tbl.Col.value('@id', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS tr
    FROM @RequestXml.nodes('//Identifier') Tbl(Col)

end
```

How can i create a comma delimited from this xml so that i can use that part of IN Clause
like

```
select * from products where identifier in (US04012VAA70,553061AA0)
```

Any help would be greatly appreaciated

Answer (score 2):

If you want put this data into  `IN` I think you will need create dynamic code.

But if it is not necessary you can use like this:

```
DECLARE @xml  XML = N'
<Request  SearchType="CUSIPISIN">
                  <Identifiers>
                       <Identifier id="US04012VAA70"/>
                       <Identifier id="553061AA0"/>
                  </Identifiers>
       </Request>
    '   

DECLARE @table TABLE ( xmlData VARCHAR(30))

INSERT INTO @table
exec [dbo].[SearchByCusipIsinDealName] @xml


SELECT * 
FROM products AS P
INNER JOIN @table AS T
    ON T.xmlData = P.identifier
```

Comment: +1: Same thought, no point in building the comma-delimited list just to have to create dynamic SQL when not necessary.